# Regarding access to private member of outer class

Tags: java, oop, inner-classes

A member inner class has access to members of its outer class (even private ones). But, the local inner class which is contained in a method doesn't have so.

Why?

One reason given to me was, that for JVM there's no concept of inner class, it creates the top level class for each inner class that's why they shouldn't have access to private members, but still it should be true for both of em.

Also, the local inner class actually has access to final members. Why is that so?

Comment: "The local inner class which is contained in a method doesn't have so" is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a comprehensive example what's accessible and what's not:

```
public class Outer {

    private static String staticOuterField;
    private String outerField;

    public void method() {
        class MethodInner {
            public void methodInnerMethod() {
                System.out.println(staticOuterField); // OK
                System.out.println(outerField); // OK
            }
        }
    }

    public static void staticMethod() {
        class StaticMethodInner {
            public void staticMethodInnerMethod() {
                System.out.println(staticOuterField); // OK
                System.out.println(outerField); // Not accessible
            }
        }
    }

    static class StaticInner {
        public void staticInnerMethod() {
            System.out.println(staticOuterField); // OK
            System.out.println(outerField); // Not accessible
        }
    }

    class Inner {
        public void innerMethod() {
            System.out.println(staticOuterField); // OK
            System.out.println(outerField); // OK
        }
    }
}
```

The outer static fields are always accessible from the inner classes. The outer instance fields are only accessible if the inner class is bound to an outer instance. That is the case if the inner class is a non-static inner class or a class declared within an instance method.

The whole idea behind inner classes is that they have full access to the outer class members, also the private ones. That makes them different from the top-level (not inner) classes, where the general access rules apply. The `final` modifier does not have anything to do here.